# In objective-c, what is the default value for a field if no default value is provided?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, default

In objective-c, what is the default value for a field if no default value is provided?
eg UIButton, NSArray, NSMutableSet, UIActivityIndicatorView, int , BOOL

And what is the different between instance variable default value and local variable default value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instance variables are zeroed by the runtime on allocation (false, NO, nil, NULL, whatever). Stack variables have no default value set; they'll contain whatever was in memory before they were put there.

Comment: Exactly right; if you want a reference see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-87015

`The alloc method dynamically allocates memory for the new object’s instance variables and initializes them all to 0—all, that is, except the isa variable that connects the new instance to its class.`

Comment: @Jonah, thanks, references are always good. I was too lazy to find it.

Comment: In ARC stack variables are nil'ed too.