# Pointer initialized

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know in Objective-C and during programming on iOS SDK, pointers are used all the way around.

What is the best way to learn whether a pointer was initialized or not in Objective-C?
Check if it is nil?

```
CSomeClass *p;
//....
if(p==nil)
??
```

PS: in other words what are the default values in Objective-C for variables? Pointers?

---

### UPDATE

Actually I have the following situation.

Imagine I have some pointers `Pointer *p1`, `Pointer *p2` in some class. Then imagine someone calls this class, i.e., it is a view and must be displayed. Then in my class I want to check that if none had initialised `p1` and `p2` (e.g., `p1 == nil`? `p2==nil`?) I want to display empty text.

Are these some sort of comparisons done in Objective-C? For example, what are the default values of `p1` and `p2` if they were not initialised? Do values by default get initialized to something in Objective-C? Maybe to null?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9581206/944634

Comment: You have answered your question about 20 times ;) Default they are just `nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the best way to learn whether a pointer was initialized or not
>   in Objective C? Check if it is nil ???*

- Yes, you are correct(By initializing, I am assuming that you meant allocation and not actual initialization of setting default properties). You can check for `nil` if you have declared it as `CSomeClass *p;` in ARC. In non-ARC, you should initialize it as `CSomeClass *p = nil;`.

So here you can do it as,

```
if (p) { //or if (p != nil)
  //do your operations
} else { //same as if (!p) or if (p == nil)
  //display error message
}
```

> *Actually I have following situation. Imagine I have some pointers
>   `Pointer *p1`, `Pointer *p2` in some class. Then imagine someone calls
>   this class, i.e., it is a view and must be displayed. Then in my class
>   I want to check that if none had initialized p1 and p2 (e.g., p1 ==
>   nil? p2==nil?) I want to display empty text. Are these sort of
>   comparisons done in ObjC?*

- Yes, that is fine in Objective C. You can check it as `if (p1 && p2)` or `if ((p1 != nil) && (p2 != nil))`. Both are fine. In the else part, you can add the empty text which should be displayed.

> *For example what are the default values of p1 and p2 if they were not
>   initialized? Do values by default get initialized to something in
>   ObjC?? maybe to null?*

- In ARC, it will be nil. In non-ARC you should equate to `CSomeClass *p1 = nil;` before doing this or else it will be a dangling pointer with some garbage value.

Here is the [documentation on ARC.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: plz see last two comments from bbum in my answer. I am getting confused now :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, Yes, he is correct on that. It wont create any error in non-ARC. It was just a sanity check which was done earlier to check if that object was not nil and then release. Actually it is not needed. You can call release on nil object and it wont cause any issue. It is just that, it can be done, but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Something important to understand here is that Objective-C uses reference counting - this is why the terminology of saying "a pointer is initialized" is a bit problematic.

The way to know if an object even exists (Doesn't mean it's initialized!)

```
if (!object) {
      NSLog(@"Object is nil");
}
```

If you wish to release an object, it's always best practice to nil it out. This way, others won't send a message to deallocated instance (causes a nasty crash):

```
[object release],object = nil;
```

Comment: Is this: if (!object)  any different from if(object == nil)??
thanks.

Comment: @user1903992, Yes, both are same. I have mentioned it in my answer. You can check it.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, I didnt understand what you said. If you meant the downvote, I didn't do it. If I have done it, I would have put a comment below that.

Comment: @ACB: i know about you, it was for Stavash. Can you please see my answer and kindly tell me for incorrect info that i have written.

Comment: My problem was with "Also at the time of releasing, check if object exists, otherwise it will create error." - Not true: this will NOT cause anything to happen when calling release. Again, calling anything on nil in objective-c is valid.